# c# How to map a string to a class in set of common classes via a static member

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need to find a class in set of classes based on a string, lets call it **ActionString** (coming from a URL entered by a user, which does not equal the class name!), create an instance of this class and trigger a class method **TriggerSomeAction()**.

So each **ActionString** ("apple", "banana", ...) should map to a different class.

- Each of these classes should derive from a common base class (for ex. CommonBaseClass) or implement a common interface (for ex. ICommonInterface) to define some common members. 1. so that I can get a list of all the eligible classes via reflection And 2. to be extendable in the future.
- I wanted the **ActionString** to be stored as static member in these classes, so I can find the right class without having to instantiate an object of all classes first.

So that a code like

```
var instance = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICommonInterface))
                        && t.ActionString = ActionStringEnteredByTheUser
                select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as ICommonInterface;
instance.TriggerSomeAction();
```

OR

```
var instance = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                where t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(CommonBaseClass))
                        && t.ActionString = ActionStringEnteredByTheUser
                 select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as CommonBaseClass;
instance.TriggerSomeAction();
```

would give me the correct instance and trigger a certain action.

My problem is

- I want all these classes to simply define an ActionString that I can compare against (best if constant, static member and unique). It would be great to construct a dictionary with the **ActionString** being the key and the classes the value.

so far I found that

- its not possible to force a class to implement a static member through an interface and
- a const field in an interface already needs to have a value and
- if I derive the classes from an abstract class I can specify a static field in this base class like

  ```
  public abstract class CommonBaseClass
  {       
      public static string urlActionString;
  }

  and override it as

  class ActionClass : CommonBaseClass
  {
      public static new string urlActionString = "apple";

  }
  ```
- but I dont know how I would force the derived class to override this field!
- also looked a bit into Singletons but not sure if that is the right path

Maybe my train of thought to solve this mapping of action to a specific class is in the wrong train station :)

Comment: I think attributes, specifically class attributes, are better suited. So you can annotate the class with some string you expect from the user with ActionString.

Comment: IMO you are going the wrong way. Either use an attribute or manually configure the mapping in a centralized location. You have gone too far in your quest to automate things and you will end up with code that may be more automated, but will have highly undesirable properties (first and foremost, "action at a distance").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Attribute class is something you're looking for. Simple example:

MarkerAttribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class MarkerAttribute : Attribute {
  public string UrlAction { get; private set; }
  public MarkerAttribute(string urlAction) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(urlAction)) {
      throw new ArgumentNullException("urlAction");
    }
    UrlAction = urlAction;
  }
}
```

Some default classes:

```
[Marker("apple")]
public class Foo1 {
}

[Marker("banana")]
public class Foo2 {
}
```

Code to create dictionary of types in assembly:

```
var typeDictionary = 
  (from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
   where t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MarkerAttribute), true) != null && 
         t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MarkerAttribute), true).Length > 0
   select new {
     Type = t,
     Action = ((MarkerAttribute)t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MarkerAttribute), true)[0]).UrlAction
 }).ToDictionary(k => k.Type, v => v.Action);
```

As for inheritance:

```
// now the typeDictionary will contain { "banana", typeof(Foo3) } entry
public class Foo3 : Foo2 {
}

// now the typeDictionary will contain { "orange", typeof(Foo3) } entry
[Marker("orange")]
public class Foo3 : Foo2 {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about having an Enum in the interface. And in the actual concrete class constructor. set the enum value specific to that type of class. I think you can do that with any other type of property too..

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar not long ago,
and it looked a bit like this : (i'm really really not sure about that code, this might need some edits)

```
public static void GetClass<T>(string ActionString) where  T : ICommonInterface, new()
{

   var c = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass && t.BaseType == typeof(ICommonInterface)).First();
        FieldInfo de = c.GetType().GetField(ActionString);
        var obj = (T)de.GetValue(c);
        obj.TriggerSomeAction();
}
```